How to convert a large file (more than 10 GiB) from ANSI to UTF-8?
I have a program that makes a backup from my database. When I try to import part of my converted file I get the error:

No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page.

This is how I convert the file from ANSI to UTF-8. Is this a good way to convert a file?
const
  cintBuffer = 10485760; //10 MiB
var
  intNb_byte: Integer;
  strFichier_export, strFichier_export_utf8: String;
  achrBuffer: TArray<Char>;
  srdFichier_ansi: TStreamReader;
  swtFichier_utf_8: TStreamWriter;
  ecoEcoding: TEncoding;
begin
  ...

  strFichier_export_utf8 := 'C:\dump.sql';
  strFichier_export := strFichier_export_utf8 + '.tmp';

  Dump.BackupToFile(strFichier_export); //<-- Devart component "TMyDump" v:12.0.0
  
  //Récupérer l'encodage du fichier exporté
  var fsmFichier := TFileStream.Create(strFichier_export, fmOpenRead);
  try
    var bteBuffer: TBytes;
    //Lire les 100 premiers octets du fichier
    SetLength(bteBuffer, 100);
    fsmFichier.Read(bteBuffer, Length(bteBuffer));
    //Déterminer l'encodage du fichier. ANSI par défaut.
    TEncoding.GetBufferEncoding(bteBuffer, ecoEcoding, TEncoding.ANSI);
  finally
    fsmFichier.Free;
  end;
  
  //ecoEcoding --> TMBCSEncoding

  {$REGION ' Forcer l''encodage du fichier en UTF-8 '}
  srdFichier_ansi := TStreamReader.Create(strFichier_export, ecoEcoding, False, cintBuffer);
  try
    swtFichier_utf_8 := TStreamWriter.Create(strFichier_export_utf8, False, TEncoding.UTF8, cintBuffer);
    try
      SetLength(achrBuffer, cintBuffer);
      repeat
        //Récupère le texte du dump
        intNb_byte := srdFichier_ansi.Read(achrBuffer, 0, Length(achrBuffer));

        if (intNb_byte > 0) then
          //Converti le texte en UTF-8
          swtFichier_utf_8.Write(achrBuffer, 0, intNb_byte);
      until (intNb_byte <= 0);
    finally
      swtFichier_utf_8.Free;
    end;
  finally
    srdFichier_ansi.Free;
  end;

  //Suprime le fichier temporaire après la conversion
  System.SysUtils.DeleteFile(strFichier_export);
  {$ENDREGION}
  
  ...
end;

I use Delphi 11.

IMHO you should not change the Encoding of your exported Files. You should prevent the ENcoding information on the Importsied of your Application. I your Target System requires UTF-8 you should export the Data Again with the right Encoding.

Indeed this would be the best method. But since it is the Dump.BackupToFile method that fills the file I have no control over the encoding of the original file.

The error means that there are few things in you ANSI-encoded file which can not be directly converted to UTF-8.
const
  BufferSize = 10485760; // 10 MiB
var
  BytesRead: Integer;
  SourceFile, TargetFile: String;
  CharBuffer: TArray<Char>;
  SourceReader: TStreamReader;
  TargetWriter: TStreamWriter;
  FileEncoding: TEncoding;
  FileStream: TFileStream;
  InitialBytes: TBytes;
begin
  SourceFile := 'C:\dump.sql';
  TargetFile := SourceFile + '.tmp';

  Dump.BackupToFile(SourceFile); // Use Devart component "TMyDump" v:12.0.0

  // Detect the encoding of the source file
  FileStream := TFileStream.Create(SourceFile, fmOpenRead);
  try
    SetLength(InitialBytes, 3); // Check the first 3 bytes for BOM
    FileStream.Read(InitialBytes[0], 3);

    // Check for UTF-8 BOM
    if (InitialBytes[0] = $EF) and (InitialBytes[1] = $BB) and (InitialBytes[2] = $BF) then
    begin
      FileEncoding := TEncoding.UTF8; // File is UTF-8
      FileStream.Seek(3, soFromBeginning); // Skip BOM
    end
    else
    begin
      FileEncoding := TEncoding.ANSI; // Assume ANSI if no BOM
    end;
  finally
    FileStream.Free;
  end;

  // Open the source file with the detected encoding
  SourceReader := TStreamReader.Create(SourceFile, FileEncoding, False, BufferSize);
  try
    TargetWriter := TStreamWriter.Create(TargetFile, False, TEncoding.UTF8, BufferSize);
    try
      SetLength(CharBuffer, BufferSize);
      repeat
        // Read a chunk of data from the source file
        BytesRead := SourceReader.Read(CharBuffer, 0, Length(CharBuffer));
        if BytesRead > 0 then
        begin
          // Convert the buffer to UTF-8 and write to the target file
          var TextToWrite: String := FileEncoding.GetString(
            TEncoding.Convert(FileEncoding, TEncoding.UTF8, TEncoding.ANSI.GetBytes(CharBuffer, 0, BytesRead))
          );
          TargetWriter.Write(TextToWrite);
        end;
      until BytesRead <= 0;
    finally
      TargetWriter.Free;
    end;
  finally
    SourceReader.Free;
  end;

  // Optionally, remove the temporary file after conversion
  SysUtils.DeleteFile(SourceFile);
end;


TEncoding.Convert  explicitly converts each chunk to UTF-8
It converts each chunk to a UTF-8 string before writing it to the output file. Directly writing chunks to the output file may not correctly handle the conversion to UTF-8.

EDIT:

BOM Handling: Checks for a UTF-8 BOM and skips it if detected. Defaults to ANSI if no BOM is found.

Efficient Encoding Conversion: Uses TEncoding.Convert to safely convert content from the original encoding to UTF-8.

Buffer Handling: Reads and processes the file in chunks using a buffer to avoid issues with multi-byte characters.

Streamlined Resource Management: Properly frees resources (like TFileStream, TStreamReader, TStreamWriter) to avoid memory leaks.

Optional File Deletion: Deletes the original file after the conversion to keep the process clean.



I don't think that'll work right. What happens if the file is already UTF-8 (or other multi-byte encoding), and the block you read ends up with the 1st byte of a multi-byte UTF-8 Code Point? And what happens with a possible preamble / B(yte)O(rder)M(ark) ?

"using a buffer to avoid issues with multi-byte characters" - using a buffer avoids too much disk seeking, but not splitting up UTF encodings. You'd have to check your last read byte to see how many bytes to seek back or to additionally read to make sure you don't split characters in between with each block read.

Also - you only skip UTF-8 BOM - what if it is one of the UTF-16 BOMs? You should use TEncoding.GetBufferEncoding to detect a BOM-marked encoding (it returns the length of the BOM and also the TEncoding used)

I think I expressed myself badly. I managed to convert the source file without error. The error occurs when I import the file using the Dump.ImportFile method called later in the code.
